# How to programmatically change default save location for office in Windows 10

Tags: office365, registry, ms-office, autohotkey

Newbie here. I am playing with virtual desktops and want to overwrite the default save location for office programs (word, excel, etc) when I change my desktop. I have an autohotkey routine that changes my desktops so I can run a script. Where is the default folder variable kept? How can I change it with AHK or may be a registry write? Appreciate.

Comment: Think there is already a software solution built into office for this: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-save-office-documents-pc-default-windows-10. P.S. This seems to be more of a [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) Question, than a [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.+com/) one

Comment: Hi, that link is for how to do it by hand not by code. Thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Believe you want to do something like these:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Options" /v "DOC-PATH" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%userprofile%\Documents" /f
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options" /v "DefaultPath" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%userprofile%\Documents" /f
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\PowerPoint\RecentFolderList" /v "Default" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%userprofile%\Documents" /f
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\General" /v "PreferCloudSaveLocations"  /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

Notice that last line. The ZERO disables OneDrive as the default.

If you want OneDrive to be your default, then change that zero to a ONE

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\General" /v "PreferCloudSaveLocations"  /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

Credit to Ramesh Srinivasan at https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-change-the-office-365-2016-default-save-folder/

His article had incorrect registry path/key for PowerPoint, I have corrected it above and below.

Here are my tested AutoHotKey examples to write the keys

```
RegWrite, REG_EXPAND_SZ, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Options, DOC-PATH, D:\MyWord
RegWrite, REG_EXPAND_SZ, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options, DefaultPath, D:\MyExcel
RegWrite, REG_EXPAND_SZ, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\PowerPoint\RecentFolderList, Default, D:\MyPowerPoint
RegWrite, REG_DWORD, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\General, PreferCloudSaveLocations, 0
```

These registry keys did NOT exist before my testing, but creating them does work. I am guessing that when the key is not present, the default location is populated using the "MyDocuments" path

This is how you can read the keys

```
RegRead, wordpath, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Options, DOC-PATH
RegRead, excelpath, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options, DefaultPath
RegRead, pppath, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\PowerPoint\RecentFolderList, Default
RegRead, cloudpref, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\General, PreferCloudSaveLocations
MsgBox wordpath [%wordpath%] `nexcelpath [%excelpath%] `npppath [%pppath%] `ncloudpref [%cloudpref%]
```